# Automation Activity report

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio

Does someone know if it is possible to extract or query the information displayed in the activity tab of the Automation (status, started date, completed date...)?

I would like to retrieve that information to create some graphics to analyze the performance.

Some of this information is already in the setup tab since the last release but it is a very high level.

[image]

Comment: There is no table/view where you can get this but it should be possible via API (therefore SSJS). I haven't check myself, but if you open the dev console under network then hit F5 you should see if any API requests are being used to generate that graph

Comment: Looks like the API being used is not a public endpoint (/rest/beta/...) so unfortunately you are left with very inefficient means by getting all the instances via the SOAP API or gathering individual automation data via REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the program (automation) and programinstance (automation instance) objects to request automation run dates/status/etc. You will first want to use the program object to lookup the program ID, then use that as a filter when retrieving from the programinstance object.

See the "Retrieve a Single Instance of an Existing Automation" section of this page for a general idea: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm